# Store *.exe file in sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server

I have .exe file that need to be stored in sharepoint. Is it possible for me to do this? If yes, how can I do it? I do not have SharePoint Designer and cannot have it installed on the laptop (company regulations)

I've tried to store the .exe file in the libraries, but an error occurred. Or is there any other solution that I can do?

This is the example of an application that I need to store in sharepoint.

[image: app]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to place the exe file into a zip file and then upload the zip file. It depends on how often this is required and by whom.

Comment: Thank you for your explaination.

Answer (score 0):

By default, executable files are blocked in SharePoint server 2010.

https://www.sharepointpals.com/post/how-to-upload-the-exe-msi-files-into-sharepoint-2013-document-library/

As a workaround, we could go to CA> Security>Define Blocked file Types> remove the exe file type then click OK.

You could also consider migrating SharePoint 2010 products to Microsoft 365 since there are currently no known types of files that cannot be added.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-sharepoint-blog/revised-end-of-support-date-for-sharepoint-server-2010-april-13/ba-p/1285559

Comment: Thank you for your explaination.

Comment: If you find any reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as answer.